# Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path Frameworks/RCTVibration.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory (React Native)

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode12

I've been having a problem for a few hours now and I can't figure out where it's coming from and I'm about to start crying.

The error that appears at the end of my Xcode build when launching the application on the simulator:

```
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /INSERT A BIG PATH HERE/Frameworks/RCTVibration.framework; 

Couldn't stat /INSERT A BIG PATH HERE/RCTVibration.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
```

I have tried several times:

- Pod deintegrate && pod install
- Delete node_modules
- Clean build folder
- Restart my computer
- Reclone my project
- Erase my simulator multiple times
- Erase Derived Data from Xcode

Here is my Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'X' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks!
  
  # Convert all permission pods into static libraries
  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}

    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
      if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-') || pod.name.eql?('RNScreens')
        def pod.build_type;
          Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
        end
      end
    end
  end
  
  pod 'X'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  # Recommended: Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

  
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath]
  )
  
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
#  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
      end
    
      if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

None of these manipulations worked so I'm interested if you have any ideas

EDIT: I have just uninstalled XCode cleanly with the temporary/cache files and reinstalled taking care to delete all the data from the simulators before compiling but same problem.

Comment: Can you post your podfile?

Comment: @MichaelBahl Yes, sorry I forgot! I edited my post

Comment: Update pods to latest version and try to remove `use_frameworks!` and erase once more your simulator